# Get error message "expected end of line" when using PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying a range from all open workbooks with the goal of pasting the copied cells into a consolidated sheet in the master (active) workbook. I need to paste the values only but get an "end of line" error message with this code

Spent pretty much all day googling my problem to no avail

```
Sub Consolidate()
Dim oBook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, bk As Workbook
Dim copyFrom As Range

'Disable Screen Updating - stop screen flickering
'   And Disable Events to avoid inturupted dialogs / popups
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the Consolidate_Data WorkSheet if it exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a new WorkSheet and name as 'Consolidate_Data'
With ActiveWorkbook
    Set DstSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    DstSht.Name = "Consolidate_Data"
End With

'Loop through each WorkBook in the folder and copy the data to the 'Consolidate_Data' WorkSheet in the ActiveWorkBook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each oBook In Application.Workbooks
    If Not oBook.Name = wb.Name Then

        'Find the last row on the 'Consolidate_Data' sheet
        DstRow = fn_LastRow(DstSht) + 1

        'Determine Input data range
        Set copyFrom = oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A6:C8")

        'Copy data to the 'consolidated_data' WorkSheet
        copyFrom.Copy _
            DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If
Next

IfError:

'Enable Screen Updating and Events
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

'Find the last Row of specified Sheet
Function fn_LastRow(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastRow = lRow

End Function
 Consolidate()
Dim oBook As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, bk As Workbook
Dim copyFrom As Range

'Disable Screen Updating - stop screen flickering
'   And Disable Events to avoid inturupted dialogs / popups
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Delete the Consolidate_Data WorkSheet if it exists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidate_Data").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add a new WorkSheet and name as 'Consolidate_Data'
With ActiveWorkbook
    Set DstSht = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    DstSht.Name = "Consolidate_Data"
End With

'Loop through each WorkBook in the folder and copy the data to the 'Consolidate_Data' WorkSheet in the ActiveWorkBook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each oBook In Application.Workbooks
    If Not oBook.Name = wb.Name Then

        'Find the last row on the 'Consolidate_Data' sheet
        DstRow = fn_LastRow(DstSht) + 1

        'Determine Input data range
        Set copyFrom = oBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A6:C8")

        'Copy data to the 'consolidated_data' WorkSheet
        copyFrom.Copy _
            DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    End If
Next

IfError:

'Enable Screen Updating and Events
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

'Find the last Row of specified Sheet
Function fn_LastRow(ByVal Sht As Worksheet)

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    lRow = Sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    Do While Application.CountA(Sht.Rows(lRow)) = 0 And lRow <> 1
        lRow = lRow - 1
    Loop
    fn_LastRow = lRow

End Function
```

Get an error message at the PasteSpecial line. Everything works fine without the paste special but, as the copied range includes formulas, I do not get the values which is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

`.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial` have to be done in 2 different lines but you concatenated the lines with `_`

```
copyFrom.Copy _
   DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Change it to:

```
copyFrom.Copy 'no line concatenation here !
DstSht.Range("A" & DstRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

For more information see the documentation:

- [Range.Copy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)
- [Range.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial) / [Worksheet.PasteSpecial method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial)

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I thought I had tried that earlier but apparently not.